# Can't get NSArray of Custom Class to display on cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

All, I'm losing my mind.  I have a class with the following code passing an NSArray of "Events" to my View Controller:

```
+ (NSArray *)eventsFromJSON:(NSData *)objectNotation error:(NSError **)error {
    NSError *localError = nil;
    NSArray *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectNotation options:0 error:&localError];

    if (localError != nil) {
        *error = localError;
        return nil;
    }

    NSMutableArray *events = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //NSArray *results = [parsedObject valueForKey:@"results"];
    NSLog(@"Count %lu", (unsigned long)parsedObject.count);

    for (NSDictionary *eventDic in parsedObject) {
        Event *event = [[Event alloc] init];

        for (NSString *key in eventDic) {
            if ([event respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(key)]) {
                [event setValue:[eventDic valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
            }
        }

        [events addObject:event];

    }
    return events;
}
```

On my view controller I've got the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"eventCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    Event *event = [self.eventData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = event.title;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = event.link;
    return cell;
}

- (void) didReceiveEvents:(NSArray *)events {
    self.eventData = [events copy];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
}
```

A sample of the JSON I'm parsing is below:

```js
[
    {
        "ID": 576,
        "title": “Event Title“,
        "status": "publish",
        "type": "tribe_events",
        "author": {
            "ID": 1,
            "username": "admin",
            "name": "admin",
            "first_name": “Name”,
            "last_name": “Last”,
            "nickname": "admin",
            "slug": "admin",
            "URL": "",
            "avatar": "1.gravatar.com/avatar/",
            "description": "",
            "registered": "-001-11-30T00:00:00+00:00",
            "meta": {
                "links": {
                    "self": "url.com/wp-json/users/1",
                    "archives": "url.com/wp-json/users/1/posts"
                }
            }
        },
        "content": "<p>Join us if you are interested.</p>\n",
        "parent": {
            "ID": 575,
            "title": “Title”,
            "status": "publish",
            "type": "tribe_events",
            "author": {
                "ID": 1,
                "username": "admin",
                "name": "admin",
                "first_name": “First”,
                "last_name": “Last”,
                "nickname": "admin",
                "slug": "admin",
                "URL": "",
                "avatar": "1.gravatar.com/avatar/?s=96",
                "description": "",
                "registered": "-001-11-30T00:00:00+00:00",
                "meta": {
                    "links": {
                        "self": "url.com/wp-json/users/1",
                        "archives": "url.com/wp-json/users/1/posts"
                    }
                }
            },
            "content": "<p>Join us if you are interested in joining </p>\n",
            "parent": 0,
            "link": "url.com/calendar/worship-service-practice/2014-12-06/",
            "date": "2014-12-04T20:09:21-06:00",
            "modified": "2014-12-04T20:09:21-06:00",
            "format": "standard",
            "slug": "worship-service-practice",
            "guid": "url.com/?post_type=tribe_events&#038;p=575",
            "excerpt": "<p>Join us if you are interested i</p>\n",
            "menu_order": 0,
            "comment_status": "closed",
            "ping_status": "closed",
            "sticky": false,
            "date_tz": "America/Chicago",
            "date_gmt": "2014-12-05T02:09:21+00:00",
            "modified_tz": "America/Chicago",
            "modified_gmt": "2014-12-05T02:09:21+00:00",
            "meta": {
                "links": {
                    "self": "url.com/wp-json/posts/575",
                    "author": "url.com/wp-json/users/1",
                    "collection": "url.com/wp-json/posts",
                    "replies": "url.com/wp-json/posts/575/comments",
                    "version-history": "url.com/wp-json/posts/575/revisions"
                }
            },
            "post_meta": {
                "EventStartDate": "2014-12-06 08:00:00",
                "EventEndDate": "2014-12-06 09:00:00"
            },
            "featured_image": null,
            "terms": {
                "tribe_events_cat": [
                    {
                        "ID": 13,
                        "name": "Community Outreach",
                        "slug": "community-outreach",
                        "description": "",
                        "parent": null,
                        "count": 52,
                        "link": "url.com/calendar/category/community-outreach/",
                        "meta": {
                            "links": {
                                "collection": "url.com/wp-json/taxonomies/tribe_events_cat/terms",
                                "self": "url.com/wp-json/taxonomies/tribe_events_cat/terms/9"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "link": "url.com/calendar/worship-service-practice/2014-12-13/",
        "date": "2014-12-04T20:09:21-06:00",
        "modified": "2014-12-04T20:09:21-06:00",
        "format": "standard",
        "slug": "worship-service-practice-2014-12-13",
        "guid": "url.com/?post_type=tribe_events&#038;eventDate=2014-12-13#038;p=575",
        "excerpt": "<p>Join us if you are interested </p>\n",
        "menu_order": 0,
        "comment_status": "closed",
        "ping_status": "closed",
        "sticky": false,
        "date_tz": "America/Chicago",
        "date_gmt": "2014-12-05T02:09:21+00:00",
        "modified_tz": "America/Chicago",
        "modified_gmt": "2014-12-05T02:09:21+00:00",
        "meta": {
            "links": {
                "self": "url.com/wp-json/posts/576",
                "author": "url.com/wp-json/users/1",
                "collection": "url.com/wp-json/posts",
                "replies": "url.com/wp-json/posts/576/comments",
                "version-history": "url.com/wp-json/posts/576/revisions",
                "up": "url.com/wp-json/posts/575"
            }
        },
        "post_meta": {
            "EventStartDate": "2014-12-13 08:00:00",
            "EventEndDate": "2014-12-13 09:00:00"
        },
        "featured_image": null,
        "terms": {
            "tribe_events_cat": [
                {
                    "ID": 13,
                    "name": "Community Outreach",
                    "slug": "community-outreach",
                    "description": "",
                    "parent": null,
                    "count": 52,
                    "link": "url.com/calendar/category/community-outreach/",
                    "meta": {
                        "links": {
                            "collection": "url.com/wp-json/taxonomies/tribe_events_cat/terms",
                            "self": "url.com/wp-json/taxonomies/tribe_events_cat/terms/9"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {…
```

I can't for the life of me get the data from the Event class to display on the table.  I have 10 empty rows display on the table with the disclosure indicator but no text.  When I throw an NSLog into the cellForRowAtIndexPath function and attempt to print event.title it logs as null.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you see? Are any rows (empty or not) appearing in the table? Did you properly implement `numberOfSection` and `numberOfRowsInSection`?

Comment: Check during cellForRowAtIndexPath check if self.eventData is nil or not ?

Comment: I get 10 empty rows which is the number of objects in the array.  And I just verified that self.eventData is not nil.

Comment: check your did recieve event method is getting called or not.

Comment: didReceiveEvents is being called as it's init'ing the self.eventData and I've check that the array contains data with an NSLog.

Comment: You never set `event.title`. Do you ever set it? Is it a property?

Comment: Can you include a sample json? The way you are parsing it is defiantly incorrect.

Comment: Sample JSON added to the post.  event.title is being set in `+ (NSArray *)eventsFromJSON:(NSData *)objectNotation error:(NSError **)error` under the section `if ([event respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(key)]) {
                [event setValue:[eventDic valueForKey:key] forKey:key];`

Comment: No it isn't. You set it by doing `event.title =`

Comment: Also shouldn't it be `for(NSDictionary *eventDic in [parsedObject valueForKey:@"results"])`?

Comment: While I could set the properties manually as you suggest, the code should be looking for the key in all of the dictionaries of the JSON and if it matches what the Event class  has for a property will assign the value of the key to that Event object.  At least that's my goal for not statically defining the property assignment.  As for `for(NSDictionary *eventDic in [parsedObject valueForKey:@"results"])` I don't think I want to do that as I don't have a key that will respond to results unless that's a function of how `NSJSONSerialization` handles creating an array with JSON data. Am I off here?

Comment: I think you made a small error with a misplaced variable. Answer below.

Comment: @RussW. Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my code was fine, but when I setup my Event class I made the attributes weak vs strong.  Once making the properties attributes strong, it retained all of the pointers just fine and everything was good to go.

Comment: OK, glad to hear you found a solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

You never set `event.title`. Also the way you iterate through the json is incorrect. If it is a property you should set it like so:

```
for(NSDictionary *eventDic in [parsedObject objectForKey:@"results"]){
     Event *event = [[Event alloc] init];
     event.title = eventDic[@"title"]; //shorthand for [eventDic objectForKey:@"title"];
     event.link = eventDic[@"link"];
     [events addObject:event];
}
```